# Is the following true: If the Jacobson radical of a ring $R$ is semi-simple then so is the ring $R$.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

True or false?

$1$. If $R$ is simple as a ring then $R$ is simple as left $R$-module.

$2$. If the Jacobson radical of a ring $R$ is semi-simple then so is the ring $R$.

$1$ looks true but I'm not sure by what.
$2$ looks false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually both is false.

1. Simple rings do not need to be simple as modules over themselves. Consider for example $R=M_2(\mathbb{Q})$.
2. $J(\mathbb{Z})=0$ is semisimple, but $\mathbb{Z}$ is not semisimple.

Comment: Why is $J(Z)=0$ semi-simple?

Comment: Wikipedia: The zero ring is semisimple but not simple - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring).

Comment: Just to confirm for 1. Is $R$ not simple as a module since $0 \subset (* 0 * 0 ) \subset (a b c d)$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$